# Add https:// protocol and www subdomain to input url if they doesn't exit?

Tags: php, regex

I have a form to accept URL inputs.
I want the URL in following format whatever format the input may be in.

> https://www.example.com

So if anyone enters below links I want to convert them to above format

> example.com
>
> http://example.com
>
> https://example.com
>
> http://www.example.com

If they input in correct format no need to change the URL.

Below is what I tried but could not succeed.

```
//append https:// and www to URL if not present
    if (!preg_match("~^(?:f|ht)tps?://~i", $url0) OR strpos($url0, "www") == false) {
        if ((strpos($url0, "http://") == false) OR (strpos($url0, "https://") == false) AND strpos($url0, "www") == false ){
         $url0 = "https://www." . $url0;    
        }
        else if (strpos($url0, "www") != false ){
        }
        else {
         $url0 = "https://" . $url0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I get your point but my situation is different, I am scraping data from a site so CURL is only accepting URL's in https://www.example.com format

Comment: Try `$str = preg_replace('~^(?:\w+://)?(?:w{3}\.)?~', "https://www.", $str);` [like this](https://regex101.com/r/cT3eT4/1).

Comment: @david please go through my question details , the first 8 words clarify that I am getting the URL in a form input.No it is not URL used to access my application

Comment: Thanks a lot @bobblebubble , I never thought it that way, its short and sweep implementation. Can you answer it below so I can accept the answer ? :)

Comment: welcome, sure! posted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a regex like this

```
$str = preg_replace('~^(?:\w+://)?(?:www\.)?~', "https://www.", $str);
```

It will replace any protocol and/or `www.` with `https://www.` or add if none is present.

- `^` matches start of the string, `(?:` starts a non capture group.
- `(?:\w+://)?` optional protocol (`\w+` matches one or more word characters `[A-Za-z0-9_]`)
- `(?:www\.)?` optional literal `www.`

[See demo and more explanation at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cT3eT4/2)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function to check out the formatting of the URL:

```
<?php
$url = parse_url($url0);

// When https is not set, enforce it
if (!array_key_exists('scheme', $url) || $url['scheme'] !== 'https') {
    $scheme = 'https';
} else {
    $scheme = $url['scheme'];
}

// When www. prefix is not set, enforce it
if (substr($url['host'], 0, 4) !== 'www.') {
    $host = 'www.' . $url['host'];
} else {
    $host = $url['host'];
}

// Then set/echo this in your desired format
echo sprintf('%s://%s', $scheme, $host);
```

This should save you (and anyone having to work on this script in the future) some regex headaches and also keeps the code more readable.